# Cannot add items to listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

```
private void DisplayFiles()
{
    lstPhotos.Items.AddRange(files);
}
```

files is a List This gives this error:

cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'object[]'

Which makes sense. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
private void DisplayFiles()
{
    lstPhotos.Items.AddRange(files.ToArray<object>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void DisplayFiles()
{
    lstPhotos.Items.AddRange(files.ToArray());
}
```

That should work. You could also bind the list to the listbox which is the preferred way of doing it in WPF and Windows Forms.

```
lstPhotos.DataSource = files; // Windows Forms
lstPhotos.ItemsSource = files; // WPF
```